# Several points were made in a question, but each point needs a seperate answer. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, answers

If a question has multiple points in the same question but they are all linked. Is there a way in stack overflow (other than the styling) to supply a heading with each bullet point so if a user can answer one part then it can go under the heading to answer that point of the question?

Or should each point require a different question? One of my own questions which I am currently working on answering is very similar to this one:

[How to determine if a database has been altered for Access, SQL, Oracle or File Systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055061/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-database-has-been-altered-then-to-push-new-dat)

I am currently working on answering each of my own points when I work out the best way so I can give a descriptive and definitive answer to help other members. Am I doing it in the correct way? Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question should contain one question, that's the basic guideline in any Q&A site.

So the question is: are those "points" questions by their own right, or just part of the one main question?

Each case is individual, in the specific case you linked to seems like it should all be under the main question as there's no point for separate question for each database.

Comment: So I'm I going about it in the correct way by putting each point under it's own set header?

Comment: Don't take it for granted, I'm only one unofficial person but yes, that's my personal opinion.

Comment: Excellent thanks for your help. I hope that by providing a detailed answer to the question if anyone else needs it it will/can be used as an almost reference guide.